# ButtonbarStyle grey Border

Tags: android, themes

Hi I do have created a theme/style for an AlertDialog. However I do have the problem with the button bar, that it's still grey even after I have set the background color. Also the Button inside the bar is not filling the bar as I expected. I tried serveral things but I was not able to get this done.

[image: The AlertDialog with the theme]

```
<style name="MyBorderlessButton">

    <!-- Set background drawable and text size of the buttons here -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_dark_border</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonBar" parent="@android:style/ButtonBar">

<!--         Define a background for the button bar and a divider between the buttons here -->
    <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertTextAppearance">

    <!-- Set text size and color of title and message here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyAlertDialogTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/MyAlertTextAppearance</item>
    <!--
     If you don't want your own button bar style use
        @android:style/Holo.Light.ButtonBar.AlertDialog
        and
        ?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle
     instead of @style/MyButtonBar and @style/MyBorderlessButton


    -->
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/MyButtonBar</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyBorderlessButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle">

    <!-- Define background colors of title, message, buttons, etc. here -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/drawer_background</item>
</style>
```

button_dark_border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="@color/drawer_background" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

How can I make the Button bar also black and the Button fill the AlertDialog again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem updating the styles file. After some time i found that the parent attribute was blocking some of my changes. Here is my styles.xml now

```
<style name="Theme.PeeDeeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/PeeDeeAlertDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/PeeDeeAlertDialogStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyBorderlessButton">

    <!-- Set background drawable and text size of the buttons here -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/primarycolor_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <!--
        Setting the weight as follows should result in equally wide buttons filling the alert dialog width,
        but instead they span further out of the dialog, breaking in multiple lines though

    -->
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonBar">

    <!-- Define a background for the button bar and a divider between the buttons here -->
    <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
    <!-- Making sure, the button bar uses parent width and is not restricted in height -->
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:height">@null</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/defaultcolor_drawer</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertTextAppearance">

    <!-- Set text size and color of title and message here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyAlertDialogTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/MyAlertTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/MyButtonBar</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/MyBorderlessButton</item>
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle">

    <!-- Define background colors of title, message, buttons, etc. here -->
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/drawer_background</item>
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@color/drawer_background</item>
</style>
```